# Kafka producer on windows does not connect to Apache Kafka Server on Ubuntu using python-kafka

Tags: python, ubuntu, apache-kafka

I have Apache Kafka installed on Ubuntu 20.04. I am trying to connect through python-kafka running on a Windows machine. When I run the producer it does not connect to the kafka server. The server is running fine. I also checked the port 9092 with tcping and it shows the port is open. I can also access the Kafka Manager from the windows machine. But I cannot from the python program.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please share your broker properties and read https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/